# iOS7 WebView jwplayer and hyper link not working

Tags: html, webview, ios7, jwplayer

After upgrade xcode to latest version 5.0, my app is not working properly.

In my app, there is a webview, which will load jwplayer to play the video, it works perfect on iOS5,6, but not iOS7.

Has anyone met this issue before? Thanks in advance

**Update codes**

```
 NSString *htmlString = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src='http://54.246.122.18:8080/cvplay/public/javascripts/jwplayer.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script><script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer.key='MyKey';</script></head><body style='background:black;'><div style='width:320px;height:180px;margin:auto;position:relative;top:-18px;left:-8px;'><div id='stream'>CVplay</div></div><script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('stream').setup({width:320,height:180,autostart: true,file: 'https://xxx.com/render/13807449869021017925092789.mp4',skin: 'roundster',modes: [{ type: 'html5',config: {file: 'https://xxx.com/render/13807449869021017925092789.mp4'}},{ type: 'download' }]});</script></body></html>";


[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Do you have an example you can share? Does it work as a web page in just mobile Safari or does it only break within the app?

Comment: Hi, Ethan, I just updated my question with my code. FYI, it works perfectly on iOS5,6, but not iOS7. It's just the playbutton can't be clicked.

Comment: Do you have the issue in the app only or does it break in mobile Safari too under iOS7?

Comment: It's only within the app, Safari just works fine, Ethan

Comment: Do you have an example of the player running? Just the link, so I can at least check that part?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem with a site that has jwplayer. When user tried to watch a video through facebook app in iOS7 (browser embedded in iOS app, webView?) it felt like there was something that was blocking user input for the player.

After hacking and slashing some JavaScript we figured out that cause of the problem was video element inside the html5 player. You can fix this by setting width and height to 1 for the video element after the player is fully loaded:

```
jwplayer().onReady(function() {
  $('.jwvideo video')
    .width(1)
    .height(1);
});
```